# Neo4j Match statement that includes a property that isn't in the database

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher

I have scnerion in which i want to attached some property in neo4j query result. Suppose i have follwoing node.

> Node :-1 Name : Raj City : Bangalore
>
> Node :-2 Name : Isha City : Pune
>
> Node :-3 Name : Iva City : London

So when i query (MATCH n RETURN n;) it will give me complete result. But I want result like this.

> Node :-1 Name : Raj City : Bangalore Status: yes
>
> Node :-2 Name : Isha City : Pune Status: yes
>
> Node :-3 Name : Iva City : London Status: yes

So status attribute will be add in result. IN SQL i know how to do this. 
SQL:- SELECT Name,City, 'yes' AS Status FROM table; will give me result with status column added by query itself.

Is neo4j or cypher provide this type of functionality? Is yes please provide me detail.

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in the same way as you suggest in your SQL query, by explicitly asking for what properties to return, rather than returning only the node properties:

```
MATCH n 
RETURN n.Name, n.City, 'yes' AS status
```